# Launch intellij via URL

Tags: url, jvm, intellij-idea

Would it be possible to register some protocol 
and then launch IntelliJ via an URL. I am
thinking of submitting the URL via Desktop.browse()
from within a JVM.

My idea is that the URL would consists of
a file name parameter and a line number parameter.
And IntelliJ would then open this file name and
scroll to the given line number. Here is an
example:

```
intellij:/mypath/myfile#99
```

Has this already been done?

Bye

P.S.:
java.awt.Desktop Class
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html

Comment: So that an application running in a separate process can open a file in the IDE. Maybe the requirement would be that the IDE is already running. But it would be also fine if the IDE is automatically launched if not yet started. Eventually something with file type association on the desktop would work.

Comment: On OSX there is an url protocol handler setup for `idea://`. I cannot figure out how to open a specific file with it though.

Comment: this works: idea://open?file=/Users/yoazm/.m2/settings.xml&line=2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [IDEA-65879](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65879) for existing workarounds or vote for the issue so that it's available out of the box in the future versions.

One of the suggested solutions is the [Remote Call](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=6027) plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [IntelliJ Platform REST API](https://www.develar.org/idea-rest-api/#api-Platform-file).
Example to check: http://localhost:63342/api/about
Use Postman to send these requests.
For me, it works on IntelliJ Idea but unfortunately, on Android Studio it doesn't work.
Asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56392911/intellij-platform-rest-api-doesnt-work-on-android-studio) question about it.

Comment: The API [now requires a plugin](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-65879/idea-protocol-handler-to-open-files-directly-from-a-URL#focus=Comments-27-6726790.0-0) instead of being available by default.  See the [IDE Remote Control plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19991-ide-remote-control).  When running multiple JetBrains editors at the same time (e.g. IntelliJ + DataGrip), sometimes the "wrong" one is listening, and I haven't resolved that issue just yet in a way that works with plugin sync.